# Adding value options in feature attribute table?

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, classification

I cannot figure out why it says `NULL`, my goal is to be able to pick values from a classificator table made in Excel and imported into QGIS as a vector layer.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Create the table in a spreadsheet:

[image: 1]

---

Save it as a *CSV* file and add it as a layer in QGIS:

[image: 2]

---

In the *Layer Properties* of the parent layer, 'augtenes' in your case, in the *Attributes Form* tab, edit the widget of the field ('EK' in your case).

Set it as a *Value Relation* type, and reference it to the *CSV* layer and field.

[image: 3]

---

When creating or updating a feature, you will see a values map with the values of the *CSV* layer.

[image: 4]